# Get public attribute from a magento model

Tags: php, magento

I want to get the a variable of a magento model. In my `app/code/community/Project/Module/Model/Module.php`, I declare a variable like that :

public var = "image_predefined";

And I want to get this variable from `app/design/frontend/product/default/template/product/extension/image.phtml`

I can get the model name with `mage::getModel($model)` where `$model` contains my model. But I can't get the attribute directly. I tried with `->var` or with `getAttribute()` but it doesn't work.

How should I do to get the variable please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could build your own "getter" for this (depending on context).

Within your model, create the following:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_MyModel
{
    ...
    var $image = "image_predefined";

    function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
    ...

}
```

Then you can call your function `Mage::getModel($model)->getImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will automoatically provide you functionality out of the box (if you're extending the base class) by using magic methods. You just need to make sure you extend the base model provided.

assuming a property called 'my_var' you can use two methods:

```
$model->getData('my_var');
```

or (using camel case)

```
$model->getMyVar();
```